# How to get Persistent menu and Get started button on messenger with Botframework v4?

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello guys i am a beginner developer and i want the Messenger UI to have the get started button and persistent menu. I can't get anything from this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button). 
I tried googling and other searches all i can see are json and curl code i don't know where to start and put them.

Can anyone guide me?
I am using C# and BotFramework V4. Thank you

Update: I got it now for future reference or others here are the codes.

for Get Started button:

```
    $ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
> "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
> "thread_state":"new_thread",
> "call_to_actions":[
>  {
>   "payload":"Get Started"
>  }
> ]
> }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=<Page access token>"
```

and for the Persistent Menu its the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send a HTTP POST request to this end point :
You can do this using Postman or from a command line.

You should replace `<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>` by your Facebook page access token, so FB identifies your page to add the persistent menu.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=`<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Also, you have to attach the data for your persistent menu in the body of your HTTP request.

Finally, add 'Content-Type: application/json' as HTTP Headers.

**Example :**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled": true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"History",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"Contact Info",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Latest News",
          "url":"http://www.messenger.com/",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"zh_CN",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Pay Bill",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
        }
      ]    
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Comment: Thank you sir but to add persistent menu i need get started button first. I updated the question the get started button still now showing.